# Coherence between two signals: How to convey the underlying idea using spectral decomposition and orthogonal projections?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, coherence

My question is somewhat similar to [one I posted previously](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/85870/constructing-spectral-components-of-signals-using-the-fourier-matrix-and-interpr/85871?noredirect=1#comment181713_85871)

I understand how coherence is defined in terms of spectral densities, but I would be elated if I could explain the basic concept of coherence, in terms of orthogonality, to my linear algebra students who have no signal processing
background.

I have two signals, `x` and `y`,  sampled at 1000 Hz for one second each. Below I enter the signals and plot the coherence $Coh_{xy}$.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import coherence

dt = .001
t = np.arange(0, 1, dt)
N=len(t)
fs=int(1/dt)

noise=np.random.uniform(low=-.0000125, high=.0000125, size=(N,))

f0=300
f1=450

x = np.cos(2 * np.pi * f0 * t) + np.cos(2 * np.pi * f1 * t)
y = np.cos(2 * np.pi * f0 * (t**1.005))+np.cos(2*np.pi*f1*(t+5*noise))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

f,Coh_xy=coherence(x,y,fs=fs,nfft=len(x))

ax.plot(f,Coh_xy)
ax.set_xlabel('frequency')
ax.set_ylabel('coherence Cxy')
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.2)
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
print(abs(Coh_xy[f0]))
print(abs(Coh_xy[f1]))

0.7405039912715564
0.9999417256272132
```

Given how the signals are constructed, the peak coherence values make sense to me.

Denoting the signals
as $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{1000}$, I can compute their DFTs using the 1000-by-1000 [DFT Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix), $W$. (I use the convention that columns are normalized.)

The frequency resolution is 1 Hz, so the frequencies $f_0=300$ and $f_1=450$ correspond to bins 300 and
450, respectively.
To determine the spectral component of a signal at $f_0=300$, I could project the signal vector onto
columns 300 and 700 (=1000-300) of $W$ and add the two results. For example, if $\vec{w}_0$ and $\vec{w}_1$ denote columns 300 and 700 of $W$, respectively, then the spectral component of $\vec{x}$ at frequency bin 300 is

\begin{equation*}
\vec{x}_f=(\vec{x} \bullet \vec{w}_0)\vec{w}_0+(\vec{x} \bullet \vec{w}_1)\vec{w}_1.
\end{equation*}

In a similar manner, I could compute the spectral components of $\vec{y}$. Below, I create and plot the spectral components of each signal at $f_0=300$ and $f_1=450$. In addition, I create scatter plots of $\vec{x}_f$ versus $\vec{y}_f$ at $f_0=300$ Hz and at $f_1=450$. For each scatter plot, I also compute the correlation coefficient.

```
def DFT_matrix(N):
    i, j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(N), np.arange(N))
    omega = np.exp( - 2 * np.pi * 1J / N )
    W = np.power( omega, i * j )  # / np.sqrt(N)
    return W

W=DFT_matrix(N)
F=f0
w0=W[:,F]/np.linalg.norm(W[:,F])
w1=W[:,fs-F]/np.linalg.norm(W[:,F])
x_f=np.real(np.dot(x,w0)*w0+np.dot(x,w1)*w1)
y_f=np.real(np.dot(y,w0)*w0+np.dot(y,w1)*w1)
print('correlation coefficient of x_f and y_f at f0 = 300: '+str(np.corrcoef(x_f,y_f)
[0,1]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3)
n_min=10
n_max=50
ax[0].plot(t[n_min:n_max],x_f[n_min:n_max],color='b')
ax[0].grid(color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
ax[1].plot(t[n_min:n_max],y_f[n_min:n_max],color='r')
ax[1].grid(color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
ax[2].scatter(x_f,y_f,color='b')
ax[2].set_xlabel('x_f')
ax[2].set_ylabel('y_f',rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
F=f1
w0=W[:,F]/np.linalg.norm(W[:,F])
w1=W[:,fs-F]/np.linalg.norm(W[:,F])
x_f=np.real(np.dot(x,w0)*w0+np.dot(x,w1)*w1)
y_f=np.real(np.dot(y,w0)*w0+np.dot(y,w1)*w1)
print('correlation coefficient of x_f and y_f at f1 = 450: '+str(np.corrcoef(x_f,y_f)
[0,1]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3)
n_min=10
n_max=50
ax[0].plot(t[n_min:n_max],x_f[n_min:n_max],color='b')
ax[0].grid(color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
ax[1].plot(t[n_min:n_max],y_f[n_min:n_max],color='r')
ax[1].grid(color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
ax[2].scatter(x_f,y_f,color='b')
ax[2].set_xlabel('x_f')
ax[2].set_ylabel('y_f',rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This leads me to my question.

**Is it reasonable to say the following**:
*When the square of the correlation coefficient between two spectral components, plotted
as ordered pairs in $\mathbb{R}^2$,
is close to one, the spectral components are close to being linear functions of one another (constant multiples even). When the spectral
components are close to being linear functions of one another, the coherence between the two original signals
at the corresponding frequency will be close to one.*

My question is based upon a point raised in an editorial found in *International Journal of Psychophysiology*, **57** (2005) 83–85:

*Coherence of a signal pair at a given frequency can be
conceptualized as 1) passing each signal through a narrow
band filter tuned to the given frequency, 2) computing the
Pearson-product moment correlation coefficient of the
filtered signals, and 3) squaring the resulting correlation
coefficient. The amplitudes of coherence functions range
from a minimum of zero to a maximum of +1.0. In
formal terms, the coherence function is defined as the
squared magnitude of the cross-spectral density of the
signal pair divided by the product of the power spectra of
the two signals.*